# Unique Value for One Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Test and It has two columns called Name and Phone_Number and I am inserting data into the test table from another table called sample. I am doing something like this:

```
Insert into Test
select First_Name AS Name,
       Contact_Number AS Phone_Number
 from Sample
```

Now I want to add a third column to the Test table called ID. This ID has to be unique for each Insert.Example:

For Instance if that insert statement inserts 2 records into the test table I want the ID to be 1 and next time when I insert 3 more records then those should have ID as 2 and so on

I thought of creating an Identity but if u insert 3 records at 1 time it will give you 1,2 and 3 but I want unique value for each insert.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question I can see that you do not want a PK, you want to call your INSERT statement several times and for each time you call it, you need an unique ID (ID for each insert batch).

Something like this: (Oracle)

```
insert into Test (Name, Phone_Number, ID)
  select First_Name, Contact_Number, (select nvl(max(ID), 0) + 1 from Test)
    from Sample;
```

And for SQL Server

```
insert into Test (Name, Phone_Number, ID)
  select First_Name, Contact_Number, (select isnull(max(ID), 0) + 1 from Test)
    from Sample
```

EDIT: isnull is the correct function

Comment: `NVL` and `Sql-server` ? don't mix

Comment: Sorry didn't realize was for SQL server. I did it for Oracle. Edit done

Comment: Same as another answer - there are concurrency issues with this answer.

Comment: @Inanov That ID column belongs to the Test table, not to the Sample table. If you look carefully at the inner select you will see I am getting the max from Test

Answer (score 3):

To get around concurrency issues (multi-user), and blocking/deadlock issues (a MAX() query can block or be incorrect if it doesn't), you need to create an IDENTITY elsewhere.

Here's an example - first create a dummy table with an identity column to provide the unique numbers.

```
create table Test_IDGen (id int identity, dummy int)
```

The TSQL batch to get the next number would be something like this

```
insert Test_IDGen(dummy) values (null)
delete Test_IDGen with (readpast)  -- cleanup, don't store data unnecessarily
select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Obviously it is better to put it into a stored proc and return the value of the last select, or at least assign it to a variable.

e.g.

```
..
declare @batchid int
select @batchid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Insert into Test
select First_Name AS Name,
       Contact_Number AS Phone_Number,
       @batchid
 from Sample
```

Comment: Looks perfect solution for my problem. Can you explain me what delete Test_IDGen with (readpast) it is doing. I mean I know it is deleting record but what is that readpast

Comment: @sam http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx It is used to avoid transactional locking. It some data is locked for whatever reason, it will just skip (and not delete those records). Not an issue since the next call to the SP/batch cleans up again.

Comment: RichardTheKiwi I didn't notice there something in oracle like `delete Test_IDGen with (readpast)`

Answer (score 2):

create `IDENTITY(1,1)` column and use your insert statement or try this:

```
insert into Test
select First_Name as Name, Contact_Number as Phone_Number, NEWID() as calledId
from Sample
```

update: same id for all inserts

```
declare @newid as uniqueidentifier
set @newid = NEWID()

insert into Test
select First_Name as Name, Contact_Number as Phone_Number, @newid as calledId
from Sample
```

Comment: @Ivanov  if I insert 3 records at 1 time it will give you 1,2 and 3 but I want unique value for each insert.

Comment: so what you want is every time you execute the insert statement to use the same id, but have it unique between executions?

Comment: @Ivanov yes Exactly that's what I am looking for

Comment: @Ivanov When I use the above code The calledId is getting value like:     D74075A5-F387-48D2-8D3D-0F05326352E1. But what I am looking for is an Integer instead

Comment: yes this is a 16-byte GUID, to do it with integer instead you will have to have seed table that auto generates the primary key and you can use that; any reason why GUID does not do what you are asking for?

Comment: @Ivanov If I want to know the recent insert on the table then I cannot see that

Comment: sure you can, @newid is the last batch insert

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Insert into Test
select First_Name AS Name,
   Contact_Number AS Phone_Number,
   insertID=(select lastID=max(insertID)+1 from Sample)
from Sample
```

Comment: There are concurrency issues with this method